# Defining bounded generic type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, clr, bounded-types

In Java, it is possible to bind the type parameter of a generic type. It can be done like this:

```java
class A<T extends B> {
    ...
}
```

So, the type parameter for this generic class of A should be B or a subclass of B.

I wonder if C# has a similar feature. I appreciate if somebody let me know.

Thanks

Comment: `class A<T> where T : B {...}` I think. It's been awhile.

Answer (score 23):

The same in C# is:

```
class A<T> where T : B
{

}
```

Also see ["Constraints on Type Parameters"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) (msdn) for a great overview of constraints in general.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds while I was finishing mine, +1 for the MSDN link.

Answer (score 12):

Very similar:

```
public class A<T> where T : B
{
    // ...
}
```

This can be used to constrain T to be a sub-class or implementation of B (if B is an interface).

In addition, you can constrain T to be reference type, value type, or to require a default constructor:

```
where T : class     // T must be a reference type
where T : struct    // T must be a value type
where T : new()     // T must have a default constructor
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can:

```
class A<T> where T: B
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this, it's called type constraints. Here is an article that explains how:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx