# Access properties of <T> object

Tags: .net-core, blazor

This is the extension method I have written :

```
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string Syngen<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, string separator)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (T obj in list)
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(separator);
                }
                sb.Append(obj);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This is where I am accessing from a razor component

```
-- Questionnaire is an class containing some properties
context.Items.Syngen<Questionnaire>(":")
```

How do I access the property of this class? (Obj) I need to access one property of this object.

I have even used Questionnaire instead of T but still unable to access obj. During runtime I am able to see all the properties of the obj, but during design/compile time, I am unable to list the properties of obj.

Comment: Have you tried adding a bound to `<T>`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933240/defining-bounded-generic-type-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: Nope, i dont know what that means

Comment: It means use the `<T extends Something>` and define the properties that you need in the `Something` class

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your objects have the same interface or base class implementing the property.

```
public static string Syngen<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, string separator)
    where T : ISomeInterfaceOrBaseClass =>
    list.Select(a => a.SomeProperty).Aggregate((a,b) => $"{a}{seperator}{b}" );


public interface ISomeInterfaceOrBaseClass  
{
    string SomeProperty { get; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public static string Syngen<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, string separator) where T : class
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (T obj in list)
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(separator);
                }
                sb.Append(obj);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

This worked

Comment: You're not accessing any property of `obj`.